# create a git branch like folder copy within one branch

Tags: git

Is it possible in some way to add a branch like copy of a folder within a branch?

something like this:

-- folder1

----subfolder1

------file-a.txt

------file-b.txt

----subfolder2

------file-a.txt

------file-b.txt

where subfolder2 is a "branch copy" of folder one, so when i change something in subfolder1, it'll be changed in subfolder2 too, but when i change something else in subfolder2, it doesn't change in subfolder1? i know in normal branches it's possible, but if i want this within a folder structure in one branch?

Bart

Answer on @bahrep 2 aug 16:

you also asked why, but i couldn't add returns in my answer :S let's answer it here for a second time.

i'm building an app with different view folders. i have a base folder, that the app will always get. When i want a file to be overruled in an other viewstyle, i can overrule it in its own folder, so the folder structure from my question will then be:

-- views

----baseview

------file-a.txt

------file-b.txt

------file-c.txt

----altview

------file-a.txt

------file-c.txt

so when running the app with de base setting, he'll get baseview, when in altview modus, only a and c will be overruled, b will be got from base.

so what i want in git, if it's possible, is when i have those files:

-- views

----baseview

------file-a.txt

```
<h1>bladiebla</h1>
this is a text for view base
```

-- views

----altview

------file-a.txt

```
<h1>bladiebla</h1>
this is a text for view alt
```

when, in base, i change the not-view-specific title "bladiebla" to "this is the header", i want it to be changed in altview too...

if i'm right, this is the way it normally works when you pull in the changes between branches right? so thats why i asked, a "branch like folder copy within one branch".

Bart

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, discussed it with my collegue now, just edit twice. it's not like a branch. case closed...

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with Git. Maintain the content of subfolder1 & subfolder2 as regular branches.

BTW, depending on your task there is a chance that [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) will help. However, it seems to be that using submodules is going to be an overkill or simply wrong in you case (just assuming).

Comment: you also asked why, let's answer it here.

Comment: okey, sorry for the multiple answers, i couldn't add returns and enough characters in the answer here, so i answered your question for more info by editing my original question and add the answer underneath it ;)